# Prevent backspace from removing html in iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, contenteditable

In order to make all the browsers consistent with the enter key in an iFrame with designmode on, I have a paragraph tag at the beginning of the body. This works great, and all browers will place a paragraph to start a new line. Unfortunately, should a user backspace once there is no more plaintext in the iframe, it will backspace the paragraph and remove it.

Is there any way to make it so users cannot backspace away the

tag? I can use jQuery or JavaScript to fix this.

```
 <iframe id="editor" name="editor" class="theframe"><p></p></iframe>
```

Comment: add a keydown/up handler and prevent the default action if the key being pressed is backspace

Comment: How would I implement this while still allowing backspace of regular plaintext?

Comment: youll have to stop it from bubblng up to the iframe level

Comment: Can you refer me to a source to learn how to do that? I'm new to JavaScript

Comment: Also, since the <p> tags are within the iframe tags, as shown by my code, would that mean that its included in the editing area?